# Get string property as JSON and not as string

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

In my EF-based rest API I have a C# POCO with a string property which contains raw JSON, stored in a varchar column in MSSQL.

When the entity is returned from the controller, the JSON is contained in a string, and escaped:

```
"options": "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
```

How can I tell the framework not to escape it, but serve the raw JSON for this property? Like this:

```
"options": {"hello":"world"}
```

p.s. & FYI:
In Java/Spring, where I come from, it would only be necessary to annotate the POJO property with `@JsonRawValue` and `Jackson` would do the rest.

**Edit 1**

The controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("{widgetId:guid}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WidgetDTO), 200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidgetById(Guid widgetId) {
        var foundWidget = await WidgetManager.GetWidget(widgetId);
        return Ok(new MyOkResponse(Mapper.Map<WidgetDTO>(foundWidget), 1));
    }
```

WidgetDTO.options is the string property containing JSON.

Comment: Could you show your controller method where you return result and the entity itself?

Comment: Very simple make a class with the properties and then add a property of that type (the new class)... So meaning the WidgetDTO should have a property which is of the type of the new class instead of string.

Comment: @Darkonekt this sounds tempting, but is not practicable in my case since the "options" field can contain arbitrary JSON.